# create vuejs form input dependency between two select tags

Tags: vue.js

trying to create a dependency between two form select options where in the second select tag i would like to show data based on the first option select. I know i can use `v-if` but it's not really giving me a solution that feels like best practice.  my relevant part of the form looks like this:

```
<el-form-item label="Provider">
    <el-select v-model="form.provider" placeholder="select provider">
        <el-option v-for="provider in form.providers"
                   :label="provider"
                   :value="provider">{{provider}}
        </el-option>
    </el-select>
</el-form-item>
<el-form-item label="Accounts">
    <el-select v-model="form.account" placeholder="Select account">
        <!--****here it is****-->
        <el-option v-for="account in form.accounts.revcontent"
                   label="account"
                   value="account">{{account}}</el-option>
    </el-select>
</el-form-item>
```

now here in my code im using provider name hardcoded -> `revcontent` but i would like this value to be the `v-model="form.provider"` value.
so incase user chose revcontent as provider what actually happenning is what show sin this piece of code but if he chose adsense for example the logic sould change to this:

```
  <el-option v-for="account in form.accounts.adsense"...>
```

I tried solutions like:

```
v-for="account in form.accounts.form.provider"
```

and

```
v-for="account in form.accounts.{{form.proivder}}"
```

but they obviously didn't work any idea how can i achive this in a way that will consider as best practice ?? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) to return the options for the 2nd select based on the first select's `v-model`like this:

```
computed: {
    secondSelect(){
        return this.form.accounts[this.form.provider];
    }
}
```

Then you can loop through this computed [property like this :

```
<el-form-item label="Provider">
    <el-select v-model="form.provider" placeholder="select provider">
        <el-option v-for="provider in form.providers"
                   :label="provider"
                   :value="provider">{{provider}}
        </el-option>
    </el-select>
</el-form-item>
<el-form-item label="Accounts">
    <el-select v-model="form.account" placeholder="Select account">
        <!--****here it is****-->
        <el-option v-for="account in secondSelect"
                   label="account"
                   value="account">{{account}}</el-option>
    </el-select>
</el-form-item>
```